# Dictionary won't let me append a string to its values

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function which takes an array of names, and sorts it in a dictionary with letters and names as keys and values. But now the dictionary wont let me append the string to the values. My code looks like this:

```
func listCounter(usernames: [String])->Dictionary <String,[String]> {
    var dict=Dictionary<String,[String]>()
    var letterList = [String]()

    for user in usernames{

        var index = user.substringToIndex(advance(user.startIndex,1))
        index = index.lowercaseString as String

        if find(letterList, index) != 0{
        dict[index] += [user]

        }else{
        dict[index] = [user]

            letterList += [index]
        }
    }
    return dict
}
```

The error comes in the line where I'm trying to add the new string to the dictionary, it says: "Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of type '$T4,$T6'" which is telling me there's something wrong with the types, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because a dictionary lookup always returns an optional - since the preceding `if` should ensure that the element exists, you can safely apply the forced unwrapping operator on that:

```
dict[index]! += [user]
```

However running a test on a playground resulted in a runtime exception - I think this condition:

```
if find(letterList, index) != 0 {
```

is not reliable.

I replaced with an explicit check for the key existence, and it worked:

```
if dict[index] != nil {
    dict[index]! += [user]
```

**Note**: I didn't use optional binding like this:

```
if var element = dict[index] {
    element += [user]
```

because arrays are value types, copied by value. Assigning the array to a variable actually creates a copy of it, so the addition is done on the copy, leaving the original array unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful. Did not know it returned an optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
if find(letterList, index) != 0 { ... }
```

should actually be

```
if find(letterList, index) != nil { ... }
```

or just

```
if contains(letterList, index) { ... }
```

But @Antonio has already explained the error message and given a solution. As an alternative, you can also take advantage of
*optional chaining*:

```
for user in usernames {

    var index = user.substringToIndex(advance(user.startIndex,1))
    index = index.lowercaseString as String

    if (dict[index]?.append(user)) == nil {
        dict[index] = [user]
        letterList.append(index)
    }
}
```

How does it work? If `dict[index]` is `nil`, then

```
dict[index]?.append(user)
```

does nothing and returns `nil`, so that the if-block is executed.
Otherwise

```
dict[index]?.append(user)
```

appends the user to the array in `dict[index]` and the if-block
is not executed.

You could also write it as a one-liner, using the "nil-coalescing operator" `??`:

```
for user in usernames {

    var index = user.substringToIndex(advance(user.startIndex,1))
    index = index.lowercaseString as String

    dict[index] = (dict[index] ?? []) + [user]
}
```

Here, `dict[index] ?? []` evaluates to the dictionary value if that
already exists, and to an empty array otherwise. And the array
of all indices can also be computed after the loop with

```
letterList = Array(dict.keys)
```